# Using IronPython to learn the .NET framework, is this bad?

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython

Because I'm a Python fan, I'd like to learn the .NET framework using IronPython. Would I be missing out on something? Is this in some way not recommended?

EDIT:
I'm pretty knowledgeable of Java ( so learning/using a new language is not a problem for me ). If needed, will I be able to use everything I learned in IronPython ( excluding language featurs ) to write C# code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, sounds like a good way to learn to me. You get to stick with a language and syntax that you are familiar with, and learn about the huge range of classes available in the framework, and how the CLR supports your code.

Once you've got to grips with some of the framework and the CLR services you could always pick up C# in the future. By that point it will just be a minor syntax change from what you already know.

Bare in mind that if you are thinking with respect to a career, you won't find many iron python jobs, but like I say, this could be a good way to learn about the framework first, then build on that with C# in a month or twos time.

Answer (score 5):

You can definitely do that to learn the class library, but I'm not sure if it's such a good idea when it comes to fundamental CLR concepts (e.g. delegates and events). You'll need to pay attention and distinguish what is strictly an IronPython feature, and what is CLR feature exposed in IronPython in a way that matches its dynamic semantics better.

Answer (score 5):

If I wanted to just "learn the framework", I would do it in C# or VB for two main reasons:

1. Intellisense - the framework is huge, and being offered suggestions for function overloads is one of the ways to find new stuff.  There's almost no good intellisense for the framework with IronPython at the moment (Michael Foord has done some work on building the appropriate info for Wing, but I haven't tried it myself).
2. Code samples - pretty much all the educational material that exists about the .NET framework is given with C# or VB.  You'll be much more on your own with IronPython.

Answer (score 1):

I find .NET a lot easier to learn with intellisense.  If you can get IronPython to work in Visual Studio as a first-class language, go for it.  If you try, please document it!

Hmmm: http://www.codeplex.com/IronPythonStudio